# Life of request scope

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I'm setting a request variable using the below code -

```
if (response.getEntity(String.class).equals("VALIDATED")){
            System.out.println("FileUploadValidation success ");
            req.setAttribute("validation", "VALIDATED");
            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/dataloads.jsp");
            rd.forward(req, res);
        }else{
            System.out.println("FileUploadValidation not-success ");
            req.setAttribute("validation", "NOT-VALIDATED");
            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            rd.forward(req, res);
        }
```

Now there is a error and I get the request attribute to NOT-VALIDATED. The request is sent to index.jsp... Evaluating the request scope I display a error msg using jQuery.

Now, again when I get a request for index.jsp,  I see the "validation" attribute is still set.

Javascript code:

```
if ('${requestScope.validation}' == "NOT-VALIDATED")
        {
            $('#error').show()          
        }
```

Comment: Looks like when there is error - the else part of your code runs whereas when you directly access the index.jsp again the same else part runs as the 
if condition does not holds true.

Comment: Can you show the coding on the index.jsp where you handle the value? I thing you are storing the value on a variable on index.jsp and in the end you dont reset it

Comment: @MaVRoSCY:I have added the code above

Comment: thats Javascript code.